# I get a "FileNotFoundError" stating that my directory doesn't exist, even though it does?

Tags: python, mysql, navicat

I'm working on a database and in one of the stages I have to choose an image for the object in question. Here is what that page looks like when I submit a new object onto my database:
[New Object Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w20v.png)

And at the bottom you can see that my image: "[bliss.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2q5o.jpg)"

At this stage clicking the submit button should work but instead I get this error: *

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 'static/images\837ef32c-db6d-11ea-b034-186024e27139.jpg'

Which I thought was very strange considering I have a [static/images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REaTy.png) folder in my directory.

I really am not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Here is my [Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH0zm.png) code

```
    @app.route("/new_camera", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
    def newcamera():
    connection=create_connection()
    if request.method =="POST":
        get = request.form
        Company = get["Company"]
        Model = get["Model"]
        PurchaseDate = get["PurchaseDate"]
        Condition = get["Condition"]
        KitLens = get["KitLens"]
        PurchasePrice = get["PurchasePrice"]

        #photo/image uploading=
        Picture = request.files["Picture"]
        picName = str(uuid.uuid1()) + os.path.splitext(Picture.filename)[1]
        Picture.save(os.path.join("static/images", picName))
```

and my [HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsRSp.png)

```
    <div class="form-group">

        <input name="Picture"  id="Picture" type="file" accept="image/*" capture />

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info" />
    </div>

</form>
```

which is responsible for submitting my form. If you have anything I can do to try and fix this code, please let me know, thank you.

I should also point out that I do have "*enctype=multipart/form-data*" in my code.

Comment: I would like to point out that your error message has an irregularity. Why is there a \ after images?

Comment: I noticed that too. I did add an extra / after "images" in the "(os.path.join("static/images", picName))" and that got rid of double \\ and only one \ was left.

Comment: I would recommend going into your file explorer and copying the path. Then compare the path names. That will tell you what symbol should be there

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good way to help diagnose relative path errors.  Before `.save()`, try:

```
import os 
print( os.path.abspath(__file__) ) # path to current file
print( os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) ) # directory containing current file
print( os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) ) # up one directory
```

With that, you can try something like:

```
print ( os.path.join( os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), os.path.join("static/images", picName)) )
```

to make sure your directory structure is as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running?

Whats your HTTP server?

Is it possible to see the HTTP(S) request being created?

Try to do:

```
Picture = request.files["Picture"]
picName = str(uuid.uuid1()) + os.path.splitext(Picture.filename)[1].replace("/", ""\")
Picture.save(os.path.join("static/images", picName))
```

I would like to also point out, depending how your HTTP server is setup. It may not actively search within the current directory.

So instead of:
path/to/the/page/directory/static/images/....

It will be:
/static/images/....